# current state in ngrx angular

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

Hi new to ngrx i am trying implement a smaple example for ngrx with angular but i have implemented everything not able to get the current state after service call

So can please help me to get the current state and how many to get the state in ngrx as newbie to ngrx and correct if there are coding needs to improved in other places

I have added the stackblitz link

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gvjoju

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reducers added to `StoreModule.forRoot()` must be an actionmap, for example:

```
   StoreModule.forRoot({data : TestReducer.TestReducer}),
```

The reducer should always have a `default` case to return the current state:

```
  default:
        return state
```